# Python - Exclude an empty line

Tags: python

This is a code for my Twitter bot that tweets certain lines to twitter, from a text file.
The following snippet is supposed to check if the line is an empty line or a line with content:

`...`

```
for line in buff[:]:
        if len(line)<=140 and len(line)>0:
            print ("Tweeting...")
            twitter.update_status(status=line)
            time.sleep(3)
            with open ('liners.txt', 'w') as tweetfile:
                buff.remove(line)
                tweetfile.writelines(buff)
        elif len(line)=0:
            with open ('liners.txt', 'w') as tweetfile:
                buff.remove(line)
                tweetfile.writelines(buff)
            print("Skipped line - Empty line detected")
            continue
        else:
            with open ('liners.txt', 'w') as tweetfile:
                buff.remove(line)
                tweetfile.writelines(buff)
            print ("Skipped line - Char length violation")
            continue
```

`...`

The text file contains newlines in between each lines and I wonder why the `if`block becomes `true` for a newline. What is wrong with the conditional statement here?

liners.txt: (the first line is a newline)

> The dyslexic devil worshipper sold his soul to Santa.
>
> You kill vegetarian vampires with a steak to the heart.
>
> There was a prison break and I saw a midget climb up the fence. As he jumped down he sneered at me and I thought, well that’s a little condescending.

Comment: you doing the same thing in all branches of your if-cascade. so you can do it afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A newline character is still considered a character when testing for line length. You'll want to strip it before checking its length. From

```
if len(line)<=140 and len(line)>0:
```

to:

```
line = line.strip(r'\n')
if len(line)<=140 and len(line)>0:
```

In fact, you can then take the extra step of just truth-testing line. Once you've stripped the newline character, you don't need to test for length > 0:

```
line = line.strip(r'\n')
if line and len(line) <= 140:
...
```

Comment: Thanks... But when I try the updated code, the `buff.remove(line)` from the `if` block throws an error: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. Also, do I need the `buff.remove(line)` in the `elif` block?

Comment: I doubt that raw escape syntax is required. `line.strip('\n')` or even just `line.strip()` should be sufficient... I doubt the literal backslash and `n` characters need to be stripped from the line